# How to setup an upload folder in openshift?

Tags: node.js, openshift, mean

Anybody please help me.. I am working a mean application on open shift.i can upload images from website.but each time i push new code to open shift the 
upload folder where images is stored is deleted.how can i setup a permanent upload folder in open shift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR environment variable.

OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR directory(your code directory) will cleaned automatically when you push your code to git